# Creating shared memory

Tags: c, memory-management, ipc

Can I create shared memory segment by not using any other library but

- `math.h`
- `stdio.h`
- `stdlib.h`
- `string.h`

The task is to accpmplish an IPC between application1 and application2 so they can read and write to their memory addresses. How could I do that ?

Comment: That does sound like homework. Is it?

Comment: This looks awfully platform-dependent to me. Which probably means **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Just open /dev/shmem, then do mmap on it.